# Why must a split view controller always be the root of any interface you create?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

In Apple's developer guide, they state: "A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create" ([see here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html)). I was curious if anyone knew why they decided that. I have a tab navigator-based application and it makes sense for the content in one of the tabs to be presented in a split view. Why would Apple be opposed to that kind of design? Thanks in advance for your answers.

-Max

PS I'm not looking for ways to put a split view controller in a tab navigator controller (that much I can figure out, even if the code does look sloppy). I'm more curious if anyone has any idea why Apple frowns on it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is necessarily a user experience decision as much as it is a technical restriction. UIKit makes a number of assumptions about how UIViewControllers will be used. Including the idea that only a single UIViewController instance has its view visible in given window at any given time. Now since Apple has access to the implementation they have been able to make exceptions for their own "container view controller" classes (UINavigationController, UITabBarController, and UISplitViewController). We can't tell exactly how much of a special case these controllers are or what they needed to do to support displaying nested sub view controllers correctly but one consequence seems to be that both UITabBarController and UISplitViewController are not intended to be used except as the root view controller of a window. Attempting to nest them within other container view controllers may cause unexpected or unreliable behavior.

I tried to cover these restrictions on the use of view controllers and some possible alternatives here: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/ Hopefully that's of some use to you but I'm afraid the only reliable way to get the UI you seem to be looking for it to implement your own split view style display within the view of a single UIViewController.

Comment: hello, I'm working with splitView for the first time. I have tab as root, then a splitview attached to several tabs as relationships, then navs etc. you said that " both UITabBarController and UISplitViewController are not intended to be used except as the root view controller of a window". Since I'm using both, then how is it possible if only 1 can be root?

Comment: This answer is 6 years old and refers to limitations of iOS 4. Today using iOS 10 we have significantly better support for container view controllers. There are still some limitations (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller notes that "You cannot push a split view controller onto a navigation stack.") but "only a single UIViewController instance has its view visible in given window at any given time" no longer holds true in modern iOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore my answer:

Because you can't resize UISplitViewController's subviews with touches?

Answer (score 0):

Apple has always placed high value on consistent use of user interface elements. Having all applications work in the same way helps the user to immediately understand how an app works even if they've never seen it before. Establishing a conceptual hierarchy of view controller containers makes a lot of sense when you're trying to help the user predict behavior.