# UISplitViewController resize iPad

Tags: iphone

How can i resize the entire SplitViewController? Smaller then the full screen representation. I want to do a representation like registration in The Daily newspaper App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you have to implement your own version of the UISplitViewController. One popular alternative is [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController).

Answer (score 0):

UISplitViewController has to be the RootViewController (there's a nice explanation of why on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853298/459116)), and I don't think you can resize it. You would need to create your own class that implements the functionality you want to have a modal-type UISplitViewController, which is what I think The Daily has done.

Comment: Yes the RootViewController would be the UISpliViewController but they managed to resize the entire view of the SplitViewController and center it.I don't know how to do that.That's what i was asking.

Comment: Oh ok fair enough - I'm not sure that you can resize a UISplitViewController because the assumption it'll always be full sized. I think Michael's suggestion of using MGSplitViewController is a good one.